# Viewing more lines with 'rhc tail' and 'rhc-tail-files'

Tags: jboss7.x, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I've deployed a JBoss 7.1 application on OpenShift. Now I have to examine the log file but with the `tail -f -n 100 jbossas-7/logs/server.log` command I see only the last 10 rows of the log file. There is a way to view whole file? Can I download it?

Thank you!

**Edit**

Sorry, I haven't explained well. I meant that I wasn't able to view more rows from the `rhc-tail-file` tool. Sorry! I have solved my problem using ssh client Putty and `less` command. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Use `less` if you want to scan more than the last ten lines.

Comment: The user is asking for how to see more lines when tailing an OpenShift app log with the 'rhc' command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-o` option with `rhc tail` to pass the `-n` option to tail:

```
rhc tail <app name> -f jbossas-7/logs/server.log -o '-n100'
```

Notice, there is no space in '-n100'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the less or cat command: `less jbossas-7/logs/server.log` or `cat jbossas-7/logs/server.log`